# Allow only a single registration at time with Rx

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is there any "builtin" way of allowing only one subscription per time for an `IObservable`?

I have created this code here (but if doesn't feel "natural"):

```
public class ExclusiveObservableWrapper<T> : IObservable<T> where T : ICommand
{
    private readonly IObservable<T> observable;

    private readonly Func<Type, bool> register;

    private readonly Action<Type> unregister;

    internal ExclusiveObservableWrapper(IObservable<T> observable, Func<Type, bool> register, Action<Type> unregister)
    {
        this.observable = observable;
        this.register = register;
        this.unregister = unregister;
    }

    public IDisposable Subscribe(IObserver<T> observer)
    {
        var subscription = this.observable.Subscribe(observer);

        var type = typeof(T);

        if (!this.register(type))
        {
            observer.OnError(new CommandAlreadySubscribedExeption(type));
        }

        return Disposable.Create(
            () =>
            {
                subscription.Dispose();
                this.unregister(type);
            });
    }
}
```

What I want to create:

```
    ...

    public IObservable<T> GetAsExclusive<T>()
    {
        var observable = this.subject.OfType<T>();

        return new ExclusiveObservableWrapper<T>(
            observable,
            t => this.registrations.Add(t), // register this  as current subscription
            t => this.registrations.Remove(t));  // release, make available for other subscription
    }

    ...
```

I want to use this as something like a single channel bus where only one actual listener is allowed. I could do this with callbacks per t but then I lose the cool functionality of Rx.

Comment: What about `source.Publish().RefCount()`? Does that do what you want?

Comment: There is support for exclusive source (Switch()), but non for exclusive destinations. What problem do you try to solve, maybe there is another solution.

Comment: @0xBADF00D Just want to build a simple event bus (wich is done and allows pub/sub with multiple consumers) and a command bus (current implementation without Rx is able to register a handle per type). I want to restrict that there is only one subscription at time using Rx, and get the benefits from link. (as in my sample above, just wondering there is no simpler solution in Rx)

Comment: @beachwalker there might be a little hacky solution. Maybe you are familar with events that have an IsHandled property, that stops the event from bubbling arround. You can adopt this.  In order to restrict access to your command you can wrap it into some kind of OneTimeAccessContainer that has two properties: Command {get;} and IsHandled {get;} If someone calls container.Command IsHandled is set to true. Onother call to container.Command should throw an exception. This is a bad hack, I don't recommend it. A getter should never changed the state of the object, but maybe you have no other choise